# A line intersecting two sides of triangle is not parallel to third side.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am trying to find out $BD$ when in given triangle $DE =12$ ,$EC=11$,$\angle AED=75$ and $\angle ABC =70$. the given side DE is not parallel to the base BC ,so the ratio of $\frac{AD}{DB} \ne \frac{AE}{EC}$

[image: triangle]

I am thinking about making DE parallel to BC by rotating the line by 5 degrees and the new point which will be present on AC will be DM where $EM=\frac{5}{360}DE$ so now the line will become parallel to BC.

Comment: Angle chase; use law of sins; use law of cosines.

Comment: using law of sines DC can be found but not of much use to find BD

Comment: You have 12 equations and 6 unknowns (one of them an angle).  That's enough to figure everything.  (But it's tedious and not pretty.)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$\frac {\sin x}{12} = \frac {\sin 75}{n} = \frac {\sin (105-x)}m$

and $\frac {\sin x}{p} = \frac {\sin 75}{11 + m} = \frac {\sin (110-x)}{K + n}$

$m^2 + n^2 = 12^2 + 2nm\cos x$

$m^2 + 12^2 = n^2 + 24m\cos 75$

$n^2 + 12^2 = m^2 + 24n\cos (105-x)$

$(n+K)^2 + (m+11)^2 = p^2 + 2(n+K)(m+11)\cos x$

$(n+K)^2 + p^2 = (m+11)^2 + 2(n+K)p\cos 70$

$(m+11)^2 + p^2 = (n+K)^2 + 2(m+11)p\cos (110 - x)$

Now it's... work.

[image]

Or using your idea in the comments, use the second image.

Comment: It has become more messy , what about that I that have written as a possible approach?

Comment: Actually, that would work and be cleaner.

Comment: Yes it would be a close approximation and exact distance would not be possible to find.+1 for your effort